# "Doping" a metal

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I had my practical exams today, where I was told to explain the structure and working of a Unijunction transistor (UJT, https://www.daenotes.com/electronics/industrial-electronics/ujt-uni-junction-transistor), during the viva. I was talking about an Aluminium rod, abundant in holes as it is a trivalent metal, being connected to a n-doped silicon base, to form the p-n junction. The examiner stopped me to correct that *The aluminium rod is doped by holes*.

I found this weird. A semiconductor is doped, but a metal being doped? Was he correct? Metals are the sources of electrons/holes. They are the dopants. And in general, do metals need doping for any purpose, if at all?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘metals are the sources of electrons/holes’? But, yes, Al does have hole contributions to conductivity (as do a variety of metals).

Comment: As in, we use metals as dopants for semiconductors. And yes, Al and other metals do have hole or electron contributions, but are these metals themselves doped for any reason? Do we introduce extra holes or electrons in a metal?

Comment: Across the range of semiconductors there are certainly dopants that are not (generally) considered metallic. I would have a hard time definitively saying P is a metal - well, yes it is, but really not like Al. As for 'doping' metals, one can make alloys which adjusts the electrical properties. But, in my mind 'doping' for electrons/holes really requires a bandgap and invoking detailed balance between the electron and hole populations. Others may differ. I'm not sure that in your exchange either was correct.